# how can i connect a button to another blade in laravel ? @include() - href="" ;

Tags: php, html, laravel

How can i make this happen , connect this button with href tag to another blade ?
i got an error with this code , is there a way to get them connected !!

```
<div class="Reserve">
                    <a href="../HtmlFiles/Reserve-3-.html">
                        <button>Reserve</button>
                    </a>
                </div>
```

[image: Folders names]

Comment: What you are trying to do is not possible. You can create a link to point to a route defined in your app and then return `reserve2.blade.php` view from the controller method. So for eg you can have a link like `<a href="reservation/alt">Reserve</a>` And respond to `reservation/alt` route in a controller method to return `reserve2.blade.php`

Comment: As a note avoid pasting links to images of code. Instead use `{}` button in the editor to paste actual code. That way people can see your code right in the question.

Comment: yess thank you so much @Donkarnash it helps a lot , i create a new controller and a link to the routes with /reserve1_view   and inside the href <a href="{{url('reserve1_view')}}"> and it works <3

Comment: Please share code, not picture of code